# Gatsby MDX - how to display excerpts?

Tags: gatsby

I wonder why I'm unable to display any excerpts on a Gatsby blog using MDX.
In the GraphiQL, the excerpt is empty and I'm not sure why or if it's ok that the body looks like a function? Maybe because of the imports and the fact that I use React components in the post?
I googled a lot but couldn't find any guidance.

1. Here is how the GraphiQL query results look like: notice that excerpt is empty
   [image]
2. This is my gatsby-config.js file.
   [image]
3. Here is an example of a mdx post.
   [image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with blog posts written in Arabic and I solved it by passing the argument `(truncate: true)` to the `excerpt` field. See [Excerpts for non-latin languages](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx/#excerpts-for-non-latin-languages)
.
I'm not sure if this is the same problem as yours since your text is already in English but this is for anyone facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are HTML elements in your .MDX file (3rd picture)

The "GraphQL excerpt" doesn't take HTML elements.

This doesnt work:

```
<p> let's imagine that the project you work on would have a sticky header and under it some dynamic content...</p>
```

This does:

```
 let's imagine that the project you work on would have a sticky header and under it some dynamic content...
```

This might help if you want to have stick to the HTML elements:

In your **GraphQL query** change *excerpt(pruneLength: 80)* **to** *excerpt(format:HTML, pruneLength: 80)*